# Using Ribbon-Kubernetes discovery with Zuul

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I managed to have ribbon dynamically discover instances in a `k8s` cluster using [kubeflix](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubeflix) and [spring-cloud-kubernetes](https://github.com/fabric8io/spring-cloud-kubernetes)

This was when I manually used `Ribbon` to communicate between my microservices.

`Zuul` automatically uses `Ribbon` for the routes defined in its configuration.

Has anyone managed to enable `Ribbon` discovery for `Zuul`? I think I would need to override the instance of `LoadBalancer` for each of the routes. Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

That was actually quite easy. You only need to specify the `NIWSServerListClassName`, the `k8s` namespace and the k8s port name in the `Ribbon` configuration:

```
service-name:
    ribbon:
        NIWSServerListClassName: io.fabric8.kubeflix.ribbon.KubernetesServerList
        KubernetesNamespace: uat
        PortName: tcp80 #make sure you this matches the port name in the k8s service (kubectl describe svc service-name)
```

Then the `Zuul` route can refer to the service:

```
zuul:
    routes:
        rm-data-store:
            path: /foo/**
            retryable: true
            service-id: service-name
```

Comment: Could you please help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58789632/feign-client-not-able-to-make-calls-kubernetes